# Save value from JSON string to .txt file in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a pretty weird JSON string from which I need specific values saved in a .txt file.

The string looks like this:

```
{"available":[{"place":"abc","stock":3},{"place":"abcd","stock":5}]}
```

So I need to extract the "place" and "stock" into a list.
So the result should look like this:

```
abc 3
abcd 5
```

I tried it with:

```
with open("available.txt", "w") as f:
  for i in list['available']:
    f.write(I['place'] + ['stock'] + '\n')
```

But it won't work. I think its because the "stock" value does not have any "". Is it possible to do what I want with Python?

Comment: `str(i['stock'])` ?

Comment: it won't work because you're creating a list with the string `stock`. you're forgetting to look up the key in `i["stock"]`

Comment: Although, it won't get that far because `I` is undefined first.

Comment: I think if you review how iterators work you should be good, can see that you're trying to get it to come together but just missing a few things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
with open("available.txt", "w") as f:
  for i in list['available']:
    f.write(i['place'] + " " + str(i['stock']) + '\n')
```

You can also use format, to make it a bit simpler

```
with open("available.txt", "w") as f:
  for i in list['available']:
    f.write("{0} {1}\n".format(i["place"],str(i["stock"])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
data = {"available":[{"place":"abc","stock":3},{"place":"abcd","stock":5}]}

with open("available.txt", "w") as f:
    for d in data['available']:
        f.write(d['place'] + " " + str(d['stock']) + '\n')
        print (d['place'], d['stock'])
```